# Several errors keep occurring in eclipse

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that opens a txt file and display information from that txt file. Java is my first language, and I'm taking java as a second language class since there's no beginning java class in my school. I'm struggling with this code for about an week. Any little help would be helpful. Appreciate for your help.

It keeps saying :

```
Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:6

at store.Franchise.<init>(Franchise.java:10)

at store.FileIO.readData(FileIO.java:10)

at store.Driver.main(Driver.java:9)
```

Here is what I've got:

Sample txt file:

```
Day1    Day2    Day3    Day4    Day5
2541.56 2258.96 2214    2256    2154
2041.56 1758.96 1714    1756    1654
3041.56 2758.96 2714    2756    2654
3563.54 3280.94 3235.98 3277.98 3175.98
2547.21 2264.61 2219.65 2261.65 2159.65
4040.55 3757.95 3712.99 3754.99 3652.99
```

Store.java:

```
package store;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Store {


   private float salesByWeek[][];

   public Store() {

    salesByWeek = new float[5][7];
   // assign the array value at index 5, t to salesByWeek
   }


   public void setSaleForWeekDayIntersection(int week, int day, float sale) {

   salesByWeek[week][day] = sale;
   // store the sale value to SalesByWeek array at the index pointed to by week, day
   // for exaample, it can be week 2 and day 3 (Wednesday)


}


float[] getSalesForEntireWeek(int week) {
   // this will find the total sales for the whole week - all 5 days or 7 days including week ends Saturday and Sunday

   float[] sales = new float[7];
   // declare an array of type float and of size 7 - name the array as sales

       for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++)
            {

                sales[d] = salesByWeek[week][d];
               // the index d runs from 0 to 7

           }
       return sales;

 }


  float getSaleForWeekDayIntersection(int week, int day) {

   return salesByWeek[week][day];
   // the return value is the arraycontent pointed to by index week and day

 }

  float getTotalSalesForWeek(int week) {

   float total = 0;

       for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++)
       {
           total += salesByWeek[week][d];

           // increment total by adding the array content salesByWeek at index week, d ( if d is the day)

           }

       return total;
       // send the value of total back to the caller function

    }


 float getAverageSalesForWeek(int week) {

   return getTotalSalesForWeek(week) / 7;
   // divide the total sales for the whole week by 7 so that we get the average sales and return it

 }


   float getTotalSalesForAllWeeks() {

   float total = 0; // declare a total variable of type float and initialize to 0 ( zero)

       for (int w = 0; w < 5; w++)
       {

           total += getTotalSalesForWeek(w);
           // sum up the total for the whole week and store it to the total variable

       }

       return total;
      // return the sum computed above
   }


  float getAverageWeeklySales() {

   return getTotalSalesForAllWeeks() / 5;
   // AVERAGE for 5 days - just Monday to Friday only - excludes the week ends

  }


   int getWeekWithHighestSaleAmount() {
   // top performing sales in the whole week

   int maxWeek = 0;
   float maxSale = -1;

       for (int w = 0; w < 5; w++)
           // run the for loop from 0 to 5 in steps of 1
       {

           float sale = getTotalSalesForWeek(w);
           // first store the total sales in to the sale variable of type float
           if (sale > maxSale)
               {    // if at all if we find any amount greater than the max sale then replace max sale with the new sale amount
                   // and also note down the contributor - in the sense that which w ( week) achieved top sales
               maxSale = sale;
               maxWeek = w;
               }
           }

       return maxWeek;

  }


 int getWeekWithLowestSaleAmount() {

   int minWeek = 0;
   float minSale = Float.MAX_VALUE;
       for (int w = 0; w < 5; w++)
       {
           float sale = getTotalSalesForWeek(w);
       if (sale < minSale)
       {
           minSale = sale;
           minWeek = w;
           }
       }
      // comments are same as the top sales except in reverse order
       // first store an arbitary minimum sale figure
       // then compare each running week's vaue with the lowest
       // if at all when we encounter any value lower than the preset value then replace it
       return minWeek;
      // finally return the minimum value in that week
   }
   public void analyzeResults() {

   for (int w = 0; w < 5; w++) // run the for loop from 0 to 5
   {
       System.out.printf("---- Week %d ----\n", w); // print a title decoration
       System.out.printf(" Total sales: %.2f\n", getTotalSalesForWeek(w)); // display or print out the total sales summed earlier in called function
       System.out.printf(" Average sales: %.2f\n", getAverageSalesForWeek(w)); // display the average sales figure

   }
   System.out.printf("\n");
   System.out.printf("Total sales for all weeks: %.2f\n", getTotalSalesForAllWeeks());    // print sum of the sales for the entire week
   System.out.printf("Average weekly sales: %.2f\n", getAverageWeeklySales()); // print weekly average sales
   System.out.printf("Week with highest sale: %d\n", getWeekWithHighestSaleAmount());   // print highest performing or top sales
   System.out.printf("Week with lowest sale: %d\n", getWeekWithLowestSaleAmount()); // print lowest sales or the struggling week
    }

public void setsaleforweekdayintersection(int week, int day, float f) {


}
}
```

Franchise.java:

```
package store;
public class Franchise {
private Store stores[];

public Franchise(int num) { // now for a franchise store
       stores = new Store[num];   // instantiate an array object of type class Store
       // the class is Store
       // the objects are named as stores

       for(int i=0; i<=num; i++) stores[i] = new Store();
  }

   public Store getStores(int i) { // GETTER display or return values
   return stores[i];
   }

   public void setStores(Store stores, int i) { // setter assign values
   this.stores[i] = stores;
   }


}
```

FileIO.java:

```
package store;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileIO {
   // Franchise readData(String filename)
Franchise readData(String filename, int numstores) {
   Franchise f1 = new Franchise(numstores);
   boolean DEBUG = true;
   int ctr = 0;
   // open the file
   // read the line
   // parse the line - get one value
   // and set it in the correct location in 2 d array
   try {
       FileReader file = new FileReader(filename); // file is equivalent to a file pointer in c/c++
       BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(file); // buffered reader will read a chunk in to the variable buff
       boolean eof = false;
       while (!eof) {
           String line = buff.readLine();
           ctr++;
           if (line == null)
               eof = true;
           else {
               if (DEBUG)
                   System.out.println(line);
               if (ctr > 1) {
                   StringTokenizer a = new StringTokenizer(line);
                   for (int week = 0; week < 5; week++) {
                       for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
                           String l = a.nextToken();
                           float f = Float.parseFloat(l);     // parseFloat will store to variable f of type float
                           f1.getStores(ctr - 2)
                                   .setsaleforweekdayintersection(week,
                                           day, f);
                           if (DEBUG)
                               System.out.print("f" + f + " ");
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

       }
   } catch (IOException f2) {

   }
   return f1;
  }
}
```

Driver.java:

```
package store;


public class Driver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   FileIO readdata = new FileIO();
   Franchise f1 =      readdata.readData("E:/Files/Salesdat.txt", 6);

   System.out.println("Data read");

}

}
```

DriverImpl.java ( I got no idea why I need this subclass, but my tutor told me that I need this):

```
package store;


public class DriverImpl extends Driver {

}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=num; i++)` should be `for(int i=0; i<num; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to change the line 10 in Franchise.java to

```
for(int i=0; i<num; i++) stores[i] = new Store();
```

Notice I removed the <= and put an = instead. Whenever dealing with array indices, one should always use the < comparator with the size as a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Valid indexes in an array are `0` to `length - 1`. Change `<=` to `<` like,

```
stores = new Store[num];
// the class is Store
// the objects are named as stores

for(int i=0; i<num; i++) stores[i] = new Store(); //stores[num] is invalid.
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot!